# accessing values of nested objects in terraform

Tags: terraform

Hi I am new to Terraform and IAC in general, so learning on the job. I am working on writing a standard Azure VM module.

I am stuck on how I access the value of a nested map.

my map variable looks like this:

```
variable vm_configuration {
  type = map(object({
    vm_resource_group       = string
    vm_rg_location          = string
    vm_as_name              = string

    vm_name                 = string
    vm_size                 = string

    vm_image_publisher      = string
    vm_image_offer          = string
    vm_image_sku            = string
    vm_image_version        = string

    vm_admin_username       = string
    vm_admin_password       = string

    vm_os_disk_caching      = string
    vm_storage_account_type = string

    # vm_custom_data          = string
    # vm_boot_diag_storage    = string
    vm_tags                   = map(any)

    vm_nics = map(object({
        nic_name        = string <<< I want to access this value. 
        ipconfig_name   = string
        subnet_block_id = string
    }))
  }))
}
```

the resource block is as below. how can I access the values of the vm_nics map?

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm_nic" {
  for_each = var.vm_configuration

  name                = each.value.nic_name
  location            = each.value["vm_rg_location"]
  resource_group_name = each.value["vm_resource_group"]

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = each.value.vm_nics.each.key["ipconfig_name"]
    subnet_id                     = each.value.vm_nics.each.key.each.value["subnet_block_id"]
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }

  tags                  = each.value["vm_tags"]
}
```

Comment: Documentation for how to do this in 0.12-0.15 is: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each. Maybe one day it will be natively supported (hopefully). You also need dynamic blocks: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, Terraform does not support nested maps with **different types**.

Luckily, there's a way to overcome it. Create a template file (`.tpl`) and parse it with the Terraform functions [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) and [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html), and a [for loop - result-types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#result-types).

Applying my idea on your example-

`vmconfig.tpl`

```json
${jsonencode(
{
    "vm_resource_group": "mystring",
    "vm_rg_location": "mystring",
    "vm_as_name": "mystring",
    "vm_name": "mystring",
    "vm_size": "mystring",
    "vm_image_publisher": "mystring",
    "vm_image_offer": "mystring",
    "vm_image_sku": "mystring",
    "vm_image_version": "mystring",
    "vm_admin_username": "mystring",
    "vm_admin_password": "mystring",
    "vm_os_disk_caching": "mystring",
    "vm_storage_account_type": "mystring",
    "vm_tags": {},
    "vm_nics": {
        "nic_name": "mystring",
        "ipconfig_name": "mystring",
        "subnet_block_id": "mystring"
    }
}
)}
```

`variables.tf`

```
locals {
    vm_configuration_template = jsondecode(templatefile("${path.module}/vmconfig.tpl", {}))
    vm_configuration_rendered = {
        for key in keys(local.vm_configuration_template) :
        key => local.vm_configuration_template[key]#[var.environment] # optional - values per environment
    }
}
```

The optional comment means you can even access another level of the object, for example, if you have multiple environments `dev`, `stg`, `prd`, etc. You can access the value per environment, here's a quick example:

```json
${jsonencode(
{
...
    "vm_size": {
      "dev": "small",
      "stg": "medium",
      "prd": "medium"
    }
...
}
)}
```

And then you can access the `vm_size` per environment like this `vm_configuration_rendered["vm_size"]`. There's no need to specify the environment key anymore since it was picked during the rendering process.

Getting back to your example, the variable `vm_configuration_rendered` is rendered like this:

`vm_configuration_rendered`

```json
{
  "vm_configuration_rendered": {
    "vm_admin_password": "mystring",
    "vm_admin_username": "mystring",
    "vm_as_name": "mystring",
    "vm_image_offer": "mystring",
    "vm_image_publisher": "mystring",
    "vm_image_sku": "mystring",
    "vm_image_version": "mystring",
    "vm_name": "mystring",
    "vm_nics": {
      "ipconfig_name": "mystring",
      "nic_name": "mystring",
      "subnet_block_id": "mystring"
    },
    "vm_os_disk_caching": "mystring",
    "vm_resource_group": "mystring",
    "vm_rg_location": "mystring",
    "vm_size": "mystring",
    "vm_storage_account_type": "mystring",
    "vm_tags": {}
  }
}
```

You can now access nested values in `nic_name` with

```
local.vm_configuration_rendered["vm_nics"]["nic_name"]
```

I used an open-source tool that I've created to render your configuration in no time. Since I don't think I'm allowed to "advertise self-content" in StackOverflow, let me know if you're interested and I'll add its name as a comment.